# Join 2 tables based on the date of an event happening in table 1, being between start and end dates of table 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables.

TableA contains

EventID, Date, **Manager**

TableB contains

**Manager**, Department, Date Started, Date Ended.

In TableB managers often switch departments so the seeing entries like

Manager1, Tulsa, 1-1-2012, 6-1-2012 
Manager1, Iowa City, 6-2-2012, 12-31-2012

Is to be expected.

I want to assign each EventID to a department based on the department the manager was in at the time the event occurred.

so for example TableA has

000001, 2-1-2012, Manager1

I want the return to be 
000001, Tulsa

If TableA has

000002, 8-1-2012, Manager1

I want the return to be 
000001, Iowa City

UPDATE:
The solution by user2034570 worked! thanks

Comment: Could you edit your question with the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join on an FK and use BETWEEN in the WHERE clause

SELECT A.EventID, B.Department
FROM TableA A
   INNER JOIN TableB B
      ON A.Manager = B.Manager
WHERE A.Date BETWEEN B.DateStarted AND B.DateEnded

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Max(EventID),Date, Manager From TableA Group By Date, Manager
```

Comment: He also wants city, this query does not return city.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have two tables as such:

```
CREATE TABLE Event(EventID INT, Dates DATE, ManagerName NVARCHAR(20))

CREATE TABLE Manager (ManagerName NVARCHAR(20), Department NVARCHAR(20),
                      DateStarted DATE, DateEnded DATE)
```

and the data contained in them (as you provided):

INSERT INTO Event VALUES(1, '2014-03-25', 'Manager1')

```
INSERT INTO Manager VALUES('Manager1', 'Tulsa', '2014-03-25', '2014-03-28')
INSERT INTO Manager VALUES('Manager1', 'Iowa City', '2014-01-25', '2014-02-25')
```

Then to get the kind of data you are looking for you would have to build your query as such:

```
SELECT          event.EventID,
                manager.Department
FROM            Manager manager
INNER JOIN      Event event ON manager.ManagerName = event.ManagerName
WHERE           manager.DateStarted = '2014-03-25'
```

You can check this here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/612e6/2

You can alternatively frame this query as :

```
SELECT          event.EventID,
                manager.Department
FROM            Manager manager
INNER JOIN      Event event ON manager.ManagerName = event.ManagerName
WHERE           event.Dates BETWEEN manager.DateStarted AND manager.DateEnded
```

You can check this here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/612e6/3

You can use any of these two whichever suits your needs.

Both of these would fetch you the result of :

```
EventID            Department
1               Tulsa
```

Hope this helps!!!